# How to open an unreal project in another python project using a button

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, unreal-engine4

I want to create a python application and within that application I want to introduce a button with will take me to a unreal engine project. How can I connect this two with the help of a button?

Comment: please provide what you have tried (perhaps a [mre] of your code and what failed), also what kind of button do you want? for that you need a GUI, what GUI library you want to use (you tell us)? please provide more details

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To open programs and for basic tkinter interface use this:

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
b = Button(root,text="Open",command=lambda: subprocess.call(['C:\\unrealproject.exe']))
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: first of you shouldn't import everything (don't use `*` when importing), second an alternative would be to use `os` module almost the same way: `os.startfile('path/to/file')`

Comment: @Matiiss On a larger project it is better to import everything at once than having twenty lines of importing widgets one by one. The two commands are nearly identical, both are correct, so not sure why I would use your command over subprocess.call.

Comment: actually on a larger project it is way worse to import everything, it can cause name clashes which are incredibly hard to debug btw and also even PEP 8 discourages the use of `*` when importing, if you don't want to individually import each widget simply do `import tkinter` and then access widgets like so `tkinter.Button` or `import tkinter as tk` and then `tk.Button`, yes there is no difference between both functions (`os` and `subprocess`), just said it is an alternative

Comment: @Matiiss You're not wrong, however I remember the names of tkinter classes and name my classes differently. I don't like to type too much.

Comment: you can still make mistakes and forget all the classes `tkinter` provides (which are approx 40 of them in the main package), also people occasionally make the mistake of `from tkinter import *` and `from tkinter.ttk import *`, I think you know where that leads. I mean if you actually know the module it isn't that bad, but still not the best practice especially because you can do `import tkinter as tk` and you got all the classes you just need to use `tk.WidgetName`, it is like 3 extra characters per widget (which is pretty much on larger scale but... you can also import each widget individual)